# Please let us vote for moderator candidates the way we vote for questions and answers!

Tags: support, election

As right now, Stack Overflow Moderator Election 2012 is going on, I found one thing missing over there which is Vote count for/against the particular nomination.

Here on the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election), you can see we have to comment something like "My vote is for you or against" and then people will give upvote to this comment if they agree, otherwise will give comment with "My vote is against you" or an argument.

So I would suggest to have "Vote up/down" system the same as we do for Question/Answers. So that people can give just cast their vote for the particular nomination without commenting more. And I think it would play a major role in electing a particular person based on the positive voting count.

[image: vote buttons]           [image: vote buttons]

I hope I am clear about my suggestion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This will happen in the primary phase (it happened for our [past](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=primary) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=primary) elections). All you have to do is wait, as we're still in the nomination phase.

The comments are there just to show support in an informal way, along with discussing the nominations themselves; the next two phases will have more formal proceedings once nominations and comments close.

Comment: Yes, so you are also agree i think, right? And we can even include this voting system so that right person can easily be selected and proceed further for the next phase of election.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: I'm saying that we *already have* this feature. You just need to **wait** before it shows up, because it's not going to happen *yet*.

Comment: Nice Information +1 for it :) I wasn't knowing that tab :P

Answer (score 20):

That is a good idea, which is why it already is part of the moderator election process. As described in the introductory text on the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/), there are **three phases** in the election:

1. [**Nomination**](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=nomination) - Those who qualify can nominate themselves, while others can post comment on each nomination. (**This is the phase we're at now, hence no voting yet**)
2. [**Primary**](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=primary) - No more comments, voting begins. **This is where you'll see the upvote/downvote facility**. (*This starts in about 4 days*)
3. [**Election**](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=election) - Each community member chooses their 3 favourites from the top 10 candidates. Final results are chosen using the [Meek STV method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method#Secondary_preferences_for_prior_winners)

For more information, try clicking on the tabs on the election page to select the contents of each phase, and read the description in the sidebar on the right.

[image: tabs on election page]

---

To get a feel of how the other phases will work, you can take a look at [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=primary) [elections](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=election).

The interface for voting during the primary stage would look like this:

[image: primary]

And when it goes to the election, you choose your favourites like this:

[image: election]

Comment: +1 Thats the exact information i would like to know.

Comment: +1 for making me your first choice in the last election. Thanks so much!

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn And thank you for the +1. Now, which mod shall I `border:2px solid green` next?

Comment: +1 for the magnifier shown in the screenshot over the description text. (Now don't tell me it is not a magnifier.)