# How to vote for a nominee in moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, voting, stack-exchange, nominations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)

I know that SO Moderator elections are around the corner, but I dont know how the candidates are elected. Does general users have some part in this, for e.g., Can I vote someone whom I think is rightful candidate or its just the current moderators who decide?

Comment: perhaps this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135056/173001) will guide you better.

Comment: Also covered by [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The election page states:

> Please participate in the moderator elections by voting, and perhaps even by nominating yourself to be a community moderator!

So yes, you will be able to vote (Any community member with at least 150 reputation may vote) and are encouraged to do so once voting has started. In fact, you will even be [awarded with a badge](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/election-participation-badges/?cb=1) if you do participate.

On the right hand side of the Moderator Election page, you will find when primary voting begins, as well as when the election begins.

Comment: I think this answer is misleading — it says "you will be able to vote and are encouraged to do so," but actually @Dave won't be allowed to vote, having insufficient reputation points (like me, fwiw).

Comment: @Roger_S Dave has 1409 reputation points at the moment on SO.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that my reputation on both SO and meta are at the same level and I didn't realize the reputation points being shown weren't SO but meta. My bad. (Actually, I feel better knowing you weren't blithely passing out bad advice.  :-| )

Comment: Admittedly that is my normal MO. But even I have my good days. ;)

Answer (score 5):

> Can I vote someone whom I think is rightful candidate or its just the current moderators who decide?

In the elections, any users with a reputation of at least 150 can vote in the primary, and in the final election votes.

When you looked the election page, the primary was not yet started. In the first phase, users who are willing to be moderators candidate themselves. The next phase will be giving a vote to who you think should pass to the election phase, and down-vote who you don't think should pass to the election phase; in such phase, you can give a vote for every candidate, while in the next phase you can give the vote for the three candidate you would want to be moderators.