# How many candidates can I choose in the 2013 elections?

Tags: support, election

In the last elections, there were 3 moderator positions available, if I recall correctly. And during the "election" phase we had to choose 3 candidates, in order. See [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work).

Now that we have 4 positions available, will we be able to choose 4 candidates, or will we choose only 3 like last time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll get three votes, in order of preference, like the last time.

The number of available positions doesn't affect how many votes each one of us gets, the fact that there were 3 positions available the last time was purely coincidental.

Comment: Too bad I won't be able to say "all my 4 candidates were elected" :)

Comment: @bfavaretto ...but at least I can say I voted for _everyone_ on the [Programmers election](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) (1 position, 3 candidates, 3 votes - if you vote, your candidate _will be elected_ ;)

Comment: Programmers sounds like I nice place to be, I should hang out there more often.