# Can a candidate vote for election in primary phase?

Tags: support, voting, election

[Any community member with at least 150 reputation may vote.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361/186599)

Does this include election candidates?

If yes means,

Can they vote for themselves?
(Since, the voting type in primary phase looks as same as the voting for questions or answers where we can't vote for own posts.)

Need clarifications about this for both Primary and election phase.

Comment: I think you already answered yourself. It works the same way as normal posts

Comment: @Lix,what about election phase

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Candidates can vote for themselves in the election phase, but in primary phase, they can't.

Comment: They often do that in real life elections too.  :-)