# What are the requirements to be a moderator?

Tags: support, moderators

I'm new in this site. I want to know what the requirements are to become a moderator?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role

Comment: A dislike for sunlight, no need to sleep, and able to mentally calculate pi to 10,000 decimal places within 4.35 minutes.. in binary

Comment: A pentient for pedantry, a knack for nazi-ness, a craft for craziness.

Comment: If you are new, you probably shouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn If you've been here for a while, you probably shouldn't be asking the question either. ;)

Comment: Surely that should be "A penchant for pedantry..." No pedants are sorry they all revel in it.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Whatever.

Comment: to be moderator you need to know how to handle any of the above comments with grace

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must be elected by the community. [Here is the most recent election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4).

You also must have these badges:

- [Civic Duty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty)
- [Strunk & White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white)
- [Deputy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/140/deputy)
- [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention)

And you must have 3000 reputation or more.

[More information about elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: The badge requirements are only for SO right now, and the reputation requirements are different on other sites as well.

Comment: Or you could get hired by SEI :-)

Comment: Do we need 3000 reputation on a particular site where we want to be a mod or total network-wide reputation need to be 3000?

Comment: I updated your answer to include the badge links/descriptions.