# Upvote and Downvote Question

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to upvote question and then downvote that question again and upvote again ad so on ? If yes, what is the consequences of this action ?

Comment: Are you trying to find the question ban threshold on Meta?

Comment: yes that is possible (within the 5 minute window), **why would you want to do that?**

Comment: Congratulations are due. You have managed to get yourself question banned on Meta, a feat few have managed.

Comment: If (as you suggested in your previous question) you want to get meta upvotes then consider asking a somewhat more constructive question. Am I allowed to annoy other users isn't really a great question

Comment: The arc of your questions on Meta, moving from "how can I become a moderator" to "How can I get banned" to actually doing so is... not encouraging.

Comment: @Oded To mark this momentous occasion, a badge should be created called the "david", for getting question banned on meta.

Comment: @Wooble actually, it's quite impressive. Daunted by the difficulty his initial challenge presented, he then set more reasonable goals, and was able to accomplish them. Real success story, when you look at it the right way.

Comment: @Mansfield - `[status-declined]`. Badges are there to encourage certain behaviors. And getting q-banned is not something we would like many to achieve, on Meta or otherwise.

Comment: @Wooble - are you suggesting the OP became a moderator before getting banned?

Comment: He did that in 5 days.  A new world's record!  I think I held it previously at 35 days...  :oP

Comment: The Q-ban is easier than I imagined though; 3 heavily downvoted, 1 at 0 and 1 positive. Seems pretty inline with stack overflow Q-ban. I need to stop making hideously unpopular suggestions

Comment: @Oded: I... don't think so. My syntax looks fine to me (but I often say the same about my broken code, so...)

Comment: @Oded No, just asked [how to become one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196307/what-are-the-requirements-to-be-a-moderator)

Comment: Obligatory (but waaaaay too late): [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: @LBT The next time we should provide that to users before they participate. Not once they are on life-support.... ;)

Comment: @RichardTingle - there are a couple of deleted questions that you haven't seen.

Comment: Very good then, I shall continue with my unicorn killing, waffle hating agenda

Comment: @Oded I know. T'was a bad joke :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do, unless your vote is locked (which happens 5mins after a vote has been casted and is up until there is an edit to the post).

It will upvote, then "un-upvote" then downvote. Then "un-downvote" then upvote... and so on. It's pretty straight forward. It won't stack the votes.