# Could we please clarify just the Primary phase of the election?

Tags: discussion, voting, election

[THIS POST HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) Has a lot of info about the election process here on StackOverFlow

The first  phase of the election process ("nomination") is pretty obvious.

The last phase of the process (the actual voting) is pretty obvious.

The middle phase, "The Primary" is confusing. I didn't really comprehend the full details of what is acceptable and unacceptable voting during this phase.

This year, The elections page for the primary phase says there are 30 candidates to fill 3 positions.

Of the 30 candidates, I thought that 7 of them wrote the most sensible presentations, so I upvoted those 7.

Is that okay? Do I need to limit my votes to 3 at this stage?

Some of my favorite guys are clearly not going to win (which is okay). I just want to make sure that it's okay to "vote" for more than the number of open positions.

I also notice that just about every candidate gets "yes" and "no" votes.  Should I vote down a candidate whom I think would act in ways that are contrary to my beliefs and thoughts?

Comment: What is unclear in the duplicate question?

Comment: @hims056 the very answer that Matthew Lundberg answered. That nuance is not illucidated anywhere nearly as clearly as Matthew's answer does.

Comment: Still you didn't answer what **point** is unclear in the duplicate question? or whole answer is unclear to you? Also, the answer in the duplicate question describes you each phase while the answer given by Matthew says what to do in primary phase.

Comment: @hims056 the "point" that Matthew Lundberg answered was, "...`You should vote up all candidates that you like, and vote down all candidates that you dislike.`..." I missed this **point** in the other message. I got it clearly when Matthew Lundberg spelled it out in a nice clear succinct sentence. In fact, I feel that Matthew Lundberg's three sentences provide the exact guidance to my original question, while the duplicate question now being referenced did not. This is the reason I chose his answer and put the green check mark on it. Matthew explained it. The other post did not.

Comment: From the duplicate question: `You get one vote per candidate in the same manner as a question or answer` I can *easily* understand that I should upvote candidates whom I want to see in the election phase and downvote whom I don't want to.

Comment: I too can easily understand it now; now that Matthew spelled it out in three sentences ten times more clearly than that other [purportedly] duplicate post. I'm sorry if this upsets you so viscerally, as the case appears to be. Matthew's 3 sentence explanation made a confusing procedure clear and easy to understand. From my understanding and observation, six other people agree.

Comment: It doesn't upset me at all. I just wanted to say you that the duplicate question is perfectly fine. I was just trying to clear your confusion. #NoHarmDone :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should vote up all candidates that you like, and vote down all candidates that you dislike.

If you are undecided about a candidate, you can simply not vote.

Unlike a normal answer, it doesn't cost you a point of reputation to downvote a candidate in the primary.

Comment: That means nomination posts are [Community Wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki) posts.

Comment: @hims056 No, it just means that nomination posts are nomination posts. The election is not a Question. It is likely that the site developers special-cased elections. Elections are special.

Comment: @Quincunx - Of course they aren't CW posts. I just added a humorous comment. :)

Answer (score 18):

No.

You can **vote for** as many nominees as you want at this stage. In fact, it's actually encouraged that you **do** vote on most **or** all nominees!

You are only limited to 3 votes in the next phase, election, once we **kno**w the top 10 canidates from the primary. (You will get a first choice, a second choice, and a third choice vote.)

No su**b**liminal messages here, move along! ;) (hint: look at the bold text)

Comment: ... and no plea for his vote for you? Shame! =D

Comment: @CodeMaverick Better? :P

Comment: Mucho mejor de!

Comment: I like it a *lot* more now! (sorry, no Spanish)

Comment: OK, I downvoted Doorknob, what's next?

Comment: You ruined it by explaining it :p

Comment: Also holy crap, my rep is 6666, amazing timing, I've got the Satanists votes on lock.