# Resulting score for nominees on primary phase of moderator election

Tags: support, voting, election, moderator-primaries

[Notice on primary phase](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=primary) of moderator elections states:

> The candidate vote scores are public when positive but the minimum score shown will be -1.

Could someone clarify, in which cases resulting score will be "-1"? I thought that "-1" will be displayed for any case when downvotes exceed upvotes, but it's not.

Currently you can check that behavior on [ruSO moderator election](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=primary).

Comment: It's if *you* downvote it: [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work): *Note that if a candidate has a negative score, the score will be shown as 0, or as 1 or **-1** if you upvote or **downvote it***

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog do you know how to explain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFPo5.jpg)? it's probably a bug when you vote (or retract vote) after score expanding.

Comment: I suspect it's down to the live refresh of the vote score not taking this into account. Refreshing the page would lead it to be reset, I think.