# After expanding the primary vote count of an election nomination, the displayed score is no longer shown as 1 or -1 on casting a vote as before

Tags: support, election, score, moderator-primaries

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361/339911), the minimum displayed score for a nominee in the primary phase can be "-1":

> Note that if a candidate has a negative score, the score will be shown as 0, or as 1 or -1 if you upvote or downvote it; if you have enough reputation to vote*, you can see the true count by clicking the number as you would on a post.

This is true only until you don't expand score votes. After that, once you cast a vote the actual (mathematically correct) negative result is visible instead of 1 or -1. See the animation below:

> [image: Deep minus score]

There's no answer on suggested duplication, I'm asking to reopen. See [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388339/after-expanding-the-primary-vote-count-of-an-election-nomination-the-displayed#comment1294751_388339) below.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you were talking about earlier. I've removed my duplicate vote and will edit to make it clearer once I'm off mobile.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog as I understand "true count" means separate number of upvotes/downvotes, but not the resulting score. Maybe this's misunderstanding from my side, but i'm not sure since it's not clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Search page for this text: ["Is your question not part of the FAQ?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/282094) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/282094

Comment: Anyway as for the question. That's no bug. The score is not really -1. Expanding the vote count shows the real votes, as it should. You can start a feature request asking to change it, or edit this, and ping me when it's wrongly closed as dupe and I'll reopen.

Comment: Why is this a problem, though? You clicked on the score to retrieve the full counts in each direction. What difference does it make at that point whether it starts using the counts that _you just requested_ or go back to using a fake number? Imo, if this is really a problem that needs fixing, it would make more sense to not allow vote counts to be expanded at all. Otherwise, we're just introducing more code complexity that doesn't resolve any real problem. Masking the votes is only supposed to protect against first impressions. If you've already seen the real votes, who cares at that point.

Comment: @animuson Just a technical question: I assume this behavior in general is implemented by setting the denormalized score to 0 on negatively-scored nominations, or 1 or -1 if the user has voted prior to the current load. When vote scores are loaded, and the user later casts a vote, the shown number changes to the sum of the loaded vote breakdown instead of using the prior denormalized score. Is that how it works in general on posts?

Comment: @animuson it's a bug since behavior is different from documentation. So either fix the behavior or documentation.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Accounting for edge cases in documentation without making it overly convoluted is difficult. As well, I feel that the current text addresses it well enough.

Comment: @Sonic Yes. The denormalized score in the database is not printed to the page for negative-scored nominations, instead always printing 1, 0, or -1 regardless of what score is recorded in the database. When you click to load the votes manually, the score recorded on the page gets changed to whatever was returned by the query. When you cast a vote either way after that, it just gets calculated by whatever is currently displayed on the page (the `data-value` attribute on the vote container), which is no longer the masked value.

Comment: @animuson if edit the FAQ is not an option could you please reopen this question and post your comments as an answer?

Comment: That's the answer, you edit the FAQ, add the info; or push for a fix, leaving the bug unexplained in the FAQ; forcing people to search for the answer - which is better.

Comment: @Rob As far as I understand [Sonic's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388339/after-expanding-the-primary-vote-count-of-an-election-nomination-the-displayed?noredirect=1#comment1294719_388339) fixing the FAQ isn't a good approach.