# Reapplying to nominate self on the primary phase of moderator election

Tags: feature-request, support, election, moderator-primaries

It's unclear from the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/339911) if the nominee can reapply if they withdraw self in the primary phase of the moderator election.

The message from the system doesn't say anything about it:

> Are you sure you wish to withdraw from this election?

If it's not possible to reapply for a nomination again, could we please update that string to say it more explicitly? In the same manner as for retracting the flag or close vote:

> Are you sure? If you retract, you won’t be able to vote to close this question again.