# Are duplicate chains OK, or just close directly against one canonical?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

On found exact duplicates, should these be voted to close directly against a preferred, or ultimate, canonical question?

Or is a chain of possible duplicates (where one question is closed as duplicate of another, which itself is a duplicate of another, and so on and so on) allowable or OK?

One example of this situation can be found [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448663/how-can-check-android-device-is-rooted-device).

Comment: If all questions closed as duplicates were in fact exact duplicates then this shouldn't happen but sometimes one of the pair more closely matches a new question than  the other.

Comment: There is situation like that: Q1 is good open question. Q2 closed as exact duplicate of Q1. So, when user offer possible duplicate for Q3, he must not allowed to provide Q2, only Q1.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135364/179419

Comment: It depends on how "exactly" similar the dupes are. It happens that Q3 looks more like Q2.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142238/avoid-chaining-exact-duplicates

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is OK in my opinion and should not be blocked.

Here on Meta I see it happening pretty often, since "duplicate" here has wider meaning e.g. any question related to how bounties work will be closed as duplicate of the bounties faq but there might be many variants which are not duplicates of each other.

Worth to mention that anonymous visitors will be automatically redirected, so in case of a chain this doesn't really matter as they will reach the "final" destination that is not closed as duplicate of other question.

As for Stack Overflow those things are more rare, but I still think it should be allowed. If you strongly feel that certain question (that is already closed as duplicate) should be closed as duplicate of *other* question you can flag it, choose Other and explain but the moderator doesn't have to agree.